# Botón Submit no funciona en modal con form dinamico

Tags: modal, submit

Tengo un modal que levanta un formulario dentro de una pagina ASP y el problema es que el botón submit no realiza ninguna acción y solo cierra el modal.

Este es el ASP que levanta el modal.

```
<form action="guardar_edit_servicio.asp" id="MyFormu" method="post">

<div class="container bg-info">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 bg-primary">Fecha de Carga</div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 bg-primary">Fecha Cronograma</div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 bg-primary">Fecha TMI</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 bg-info">
            <%response.write(verfecha(RS_EServ("F_Carga"),"d"))%>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 bg-info">
            <%
            If solo_lectura="si" then
                response.write("<input NAME='VS_CRONO' type='date' class='combo_box_f' id='VS_CRONO' size='100' value='" & RS_EServ("F_Cronograma") &"' readonly>")
            else
                response.write("<input NAME='VS_CRONO' type='date' class='combo_box_f' id='VS_CRONO' size='100' value='" & RS_EServ("F_Cronograma") &"' required>")
            end if
            %>


        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 bg-info">
            <%
            if solo_lectura="si" then
                response.write("<input NAME='VS_TMI' type='date' class='combo_box_f' id='VS_TMI' size='100' value='" & RS_EServ("F_TMI") & "' readonly>")
            else
                response.write("<input NAME='VS_TMI' type='date' class='combo_box_f' id='VS_TMI' size='100' value='" & RS_EServ("F_TMI") & "'>")
            end if
            %>
        </div>      
    </div>

    <div clas="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12" align="center">
            <%
            if solo_lectura="si" then 
                response.write("<button type='submit' id='btn_enviar' value='Grabar' name='btn_enviar' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' disabled>Grabar</button>")

            else
                response.write("<button type='submit' tabindex='-1' id='btn_enviar' value='Grabar' name='btn_enviar' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>Grabar</button>")

            end if
            %>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</form>
```

Si utilizo la pagina ASP directamente (y no contenida en el modal) funciona correctamente pero no lo hace cuando la uso dentro del modal.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

resolví el problema colocando el parte del formulario en la pagina que llama al modal y ahora funciona!

El código quedo así:

`

```
<!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content" style="float:left;width:inherit;height:inherit;margin:0 auto;">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="modal-title">    
            <h3>
                <span class="label label-info">Servicio del Proyecto Nro.: <%response.write(nro_ticket)%></span>
            </h3>
            <%
            if solo_lectura="si" then
                response.write("<h5 class='bg-danger'>Proyecto Finalizado</h5>")
            else

            end if
            %>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="table-responsive" style="width:100%">
                <form action="guardar_edit_servicio.asp" id="MyFormu" method="post">
                    <div clas="row">
                        <div id="txtHint2">Customer info will be listed here...</div>
                    </div>
                    <div clas="row" align="center">
                    <%
                    if solo_lectura="si" then 
                        response.write("<button type='submit' id='btn_enviar' value='Grabar' name='btn_enviar' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' disabled>Grabar</button>")

                    else
                        response.write("<button type='submit' tabindex='-1' id='btn_enviar' name='btn_enviar' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>Grabar</button>")

                    end if
                    %>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

Y con el agregado de esta función

```
$(document).on("submit", "#MyFormu", function (e) {
event.preventDefault();
console.log("asdasdasdasds");});
```

Espero que le sirva a alguien mas.

Saludos